# TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float . When showing image from neural net

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

When I run the code I get this error. I am using the guide from the Tensorflow Website for the Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Network, https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/generative/dcgan#what_are_gans
I am copy/pasting from that site.

I've gone through other questions on stackoverflow but none of them answer my question.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time

from IPython import display
(train_images, train_labels), (_, _) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0], 28, 28, 1).astype('float32')
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]
BUFFER_SIZE = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 256
def make_generator_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(7*7*256, use_bias=False, input_shape=(100,)))
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Reshape((7, 7, 256)))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 256) # Note: None is the batch size

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 7, 7, 128)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 14, 14, 64)
    model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())

    model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', use_bias=False, activation='tanh'))
    assert model.output_shape == (None, 28, 28, 1)

    return model

generator = make_generator_model()

noise = tf.random.normal([1, 100])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

plt.imshow(generated_image[0, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
```

It should show a blurry image.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run above code by enabling eager execution at the start of the program. Add below line after the tensorflow import statement:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
```